# I am trying to find customers in Netsuite by using a custom field using java api using 2016_1 endpoint

Tags: java

```
SearchCustomFieldList searchCustomFieldList = new SearchCustomFieldList();
            SearchCustomField[] searchCustomFieldsArr = new SearchCustomField[1];

            SearchStringCustomField searchStringCustomField = new SearchStringCustomField();    
            SearchCustomField customefield=new SearchCustomField() {};
            customefield.setInternalId("custentity_seq_1_hrp_client_id");       

            searchStringCustomField.setOperator(SearchStringFieldOperator.is);
            searchStringCustomField.setSearchValue(customerid);

            searchCustomFieldsArr[0] = searchStringCustomField;

            searchCustomFieldList.setCustomField(searchCustomFieldsArr);
            searchCustomFieldList.setCustomField(0, customefield);
            customerSearchBasic.setCustomFieldList(searchCustomFieldList);

            SearchResult searchResult = nsPort.search(customerSearchBasic);
```

I have got this error:

> "org.xml.sax.SAXException: {urn:core_2016_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchCustomField is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated"

Comment: any one can help me to find out the solution